# P2P Connection with Sockets on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

I'm doing one university homework, where I need to make the Chinese Checkers game work via sockets.

I've followed this [tutorial on raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3437391-real-time-communication-with-streams-tutorial-for-ios) and it seems easy setting up the streams, but in this tutorial its used a local server to intermediate the connection, and I don't know how to make a server, so I kinda need to make the connection be p2p, but i don't know how I'm going to discover the IP and Port the app is running on iOS.

Personally, it's the first time I've seen about sockets and I really need help.

If you guys can teach me how to connect 2 apps to each other directly  USING SOCKETS (otherwise my teacher won't accept it) or point me where I can learn how to make a simple server for this matter it would be really great.

P.S: I know I can use GameKit, MultipeerConnectivity and etc for it, but I'm really obligated to use sockets :/

Comment: You can use MultipeerConnectivity framework: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity

Comment: Yeah, i stated that in my comment, but the problem is that it is college homework, so I'm stuck with using what my teacher wants, that for Swift is basically CFStreams.

Comment: I found this post similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210835/is-it-possible-to-connect-two-ios-devices-using-sockets-by-getting-their-ip-addr

Comment: You can find an explanation and diagram here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59439022/4067700 and look at implementation https://github.com/filimo/ReaderTranslator/tree/master/ReaderTranslator/Networking